# Approach and Algorithm for checking availability for schedule using PHPmyadmin and SQL

Tags: php, sql, algorithm

**UPDATED**

I'm trying to create a basic schedule for all students in their final year to present their final project to 2 supervisors. I have successfully created a schedule with no constraints but now i need to create a schedule based on the supervisors availability.

Here is a detailed description of the problem.

A student is assigned a supervisor and a supervisor will supervise more than one student.  The supervisor also teaches classes during the day. Now i need to create a schedule for all of the students to present to their supervisor and one additional supervisor that supervises other students. (for the moment I'm focusing on the supervisors that are assigned to the student and not the second one until i get it working.

I want to compare the supervisors availability for the slots time if they're free then assign them to the slot and then update the availability of that time to false to avoid double booking using a PHP sql query.

so...

What i have done so far:

```
// get all of the Slots. 
    $sql = "SELECT Slot_ID  FROM slot WHERE  StartTime < '18:00:00'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $DayTimeSlots = array(); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $DayTimeSlots [] = $row;

        }
    }

// Store slots into simple array 

    function extractSlotId($DayTimeSlots){
    return $DayTimeSlots['Slot_ID'];

    }

    $slots = array_map("extractSlotId",$DayTimeSlots);

    // SHOW SLOTS
    foreach ($slots as $slotID) {
    echo " SlotID:  = $slotID <br>"; 

    }

    // Get All students 


    $sql = "SELECT Student_ID FROM student WHERE PartTime =0"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $FullTimeStudents = array(); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $FullTimeStudents [] = $row;

        }
    }


  // Store into a simple array 


    // Extract student id and Supervisor_ID 

    function extractStudentId($FullTimeStudents){
    return $FullTimeStudents['Student_ID'];

    }

    $students = array_map("extractStudentId",$FullTimeStudents);


    // Combine the Slot and Students array 

    $min = min(count($FullTimeStudents), count($DayTimeSlots));
    $result = array_combine(array_slice($students , 0, $min), array_slice($slots, 0, $min));

     foreach($result as $key=>$value){ // $Key = Student_ID, $value = Slot_ID
        echo " $key : $value "; 

        // get supervisor ID 

    $sql = "select Supervisor_ID FROM student where Student_ID = $key";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
    $SuperID = $row['Supervisor_ID'];
    echo  "SuperID : $SuperID "; 

    // get slotID 

    $sql = "select Date, StartTime FROM Slot where Slot_ID = $value";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
    $Date = $row['Date'];
    $StartTime = $row['StartTime'];
    echo  "Slot Date : $Date Start Time : $StartTime "; 

        // get Date id 

    $sql = "select Date_ID FROM dates where Date = '$Date'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
    $DateID = $row['Date_ID'];
    echo  "Date ID : $DateID "; 

    // Check if the supervisor is available 

    $sql = "select `$StartTime` FROM supervisor_availability where Date_ID = $DateID AND Supervisor_ID = $SuperID";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
    $Available = $row["$StartTime"];
    echo  "Is the Lecture Available?  : $Available  "; 
    $Time = "`$StartTime`"; 

    if($Available == 1){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO student_slot (Student_ID, Slot_ID) VALUES ($key, $value)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $sql = "UPDATE `supervisor_availability` SET $Time = '0' WHERE `supervisor_availability`.`Supervisor_ID` = $SuperID AND `supervisor_availability`.`Date_ID` = $DateID" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 


    } else if ($Available == 0) {

        // Not sure what to do here. 
        // Can i make the Slot it's currently checking go to the end of the 
        // array for a different student and then check the next slot and come 
        // back to it.  
    }
     }
```

I'm using echo for debugging.

The algorithm works fine if the Supervisor is available,  it assigns it correctly and then updates the Supervisors availability for that time slot

Just need help with how to handle it if they're not available.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

[Supervisor_Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrPcO.png) [Slot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSegE.png) [Student Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUATD.png) [Date Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiY9J.png) [DB_Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YK0b.png)

Comment: Have you considered a Supervisor table that contains just the Time Slots during which they are busy? It looks like you have time slots already organized by ID, which is a start. Instead of an `INNER JOIN` you would instead use a `WHERE` clause like so (sorry about the formatting):      `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Supervisor_Busy s2 WHERE s2.Supervisor_ID = stud.Supervisor_ID AND s2.Slot_ID = ss.Slot_ID)`  Your Supervisor_Busy table would be just 2 columns: Supervisor_ID and Slot_ID, and you would need to add to it each time they are scheduled to teach.

Comment: The way i currently have it is a supervisor table with the supervisor_ID and Supervisor name in it which links up to the students that they are supervising.  The way i have it now is a table that contains there ID and the Date_ID and 12 Columns (09:00:00|10:00:00| 11:00:00) etc and under those columns i have a Boolean if they're free or not.  It's not so much the view i'm struggling with i just need some guidance on what data to extract into PHP arrays and what to loop on.  I know it will be complex but i just need a good starting point.  I'll update the question with some pseudo code.

Comment: Your Supervisor_Availability is a "wide" table, and would be better if you normalized it. I would suggest adding a Time_Slot_Dim table like so:  Time_Slot_ID (Surrogate Key), Date_ID, Time Slot. This will allow your Supervisor_Availability table to be only two columns wide: Supervisor_ID and Time_Slot_ID (and a 3rd column if you still want to keep the BIT / Boolean column for availability). This will also allow you to keep looping on the Supervisor_Availability rows until you find a free time slot. Use nested loops for this -- Students (outer loop) and Supervisor_Availability (inner loop)